# How to check is there a process running with the given handle

Tags: delphi, executable, handle, auto-update

Scenario:
From App1, I need to execute App2 passing App1.Handle as param.
App2 should wait until App1's close. After this, App2 should replace App1.exe file with an updated version.

- Are there better ways to update a running executable file?
- If there aren't.. In App2, I know App1.Handle and I should check
  if App1 has been closed. How can this be verified starting from
  App1.Handle?

EDIT:

App1:

```
var
  ProcessHandle : THandle;
begin
  ProcessHandle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, GetCurrentProcessId());
  //Is PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS needed?
  ShellExecute(0, 'open', 'App2.exe', PChar(IntToStr(ProcessHandle)), '.\', SW_SHOW);
end;
```

App2:

```
var
  SenderHandle : THandle;
begin
  if(ParamStr(1) <> '') then
  begin
    SenderHandle := StrToInt(ParamStr(1));
    WaitForSingleObject(SenderHandle, INFINITE);
    ShowMessage('App1 Terminated!');
    //Showmessage is executed when App1 is still running, what's wrong?
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The handle should be inheritable, read documentation of OpenProcess. Also, you should use CreateProcess accordingly (handle inheritance - refer to docs) instead of ShellExecute. You don't need all access, synchronize is enough. And you should be checking return of the APIs, you'd then know your wait function is returning WAIT_FAILED.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: I did as suggested and it works fine! Thanks for comment!

Comment: Well done, admittedly my comment wasn't very verbose. And you're welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`App1.Handle` implies a *window handle*.  App2 needs to wait on App1's *process handle* instead. To get App1's process handle, use `OpenProcess()` with `GetCurrentProcessId()` as the process ID, or `DuplicateHandle()` with `GetCurrentProcess()` as the source handle.  Then you can pass the handle to App2, and have App2 wait on it using `WaitForSingleObject()`.  The handle will be signaled when App1 exits.  Then App2 can close the handle and replace App1.exe.

Comment: Why to use OpenProcess(GetCurrentThreadId()) instead of DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess()) or vice versa? (I mean, which are differences?).

Comment: Just two different ways to obtain App1's real handle, as `GetCurrentProcess()` returns a pseudo handle that is not suitable for passing to App2. However, `DuplicateHandle()` would require App2 to already be running, so the duped handle will have to be passed to App2 by IPC, not a command line.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I was summarizing, so I left out some details that are in the documentation. But yes, it takes a process id instead of a thread id, so use `GetCurrentProcessId()` instead.

Comment: The call to OpenProcess is wrong, the retrieved handle will not be valid in the other process, that's why DuplicateHandle exists. I'd just pass the PID and let the other application open a synchronize handle itself.

Comment: @Sertac that won't work. When the first process closes the pid will not be valid. Passing a process handle is the only way. OpenProcess can return an inheritable handle.

Comment: @David - Isn't the point to wait till the first process closes? If the PID is not valid and OpenProcess fails, then app2 can replace app1 immediately. You're right on the second point.

Comment: Is there a possibility that there will be multiple instances of App1 started?

Comment: @VitaliyG: Yes but App1 checks if there are other running instances. If it's so, update is skipped.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I have some difficulties about how to proceed. Could you please explain how to pratically implement this solution?

Answer (score -1):

Why wait for the process to terminate using a PID? Why not just try to overwrite the file? As long as the process is still running, you cannot overwrite the .EXE file.

Ie. something like:

```
WHILE NOT CopyFile(NewVersion,InstalledVersion) DO Sleep(100);
```

Of course you could incorporate a time-out and other safeguards, but the above shows you another way to do it without needing a PID or other value to test for...

Comment: Dowwnvote on a point of principle. Polling is never to be used when the system provides blocking mechanisms.

Comment: But the solution he asks for has a lot of failure possibilities - f.ex. if two instances of the program is running, then he still won't be able to overwrite the file. The above solution will test for what he *really* wants - the ability to overwrite the file. He really doesn't care if the program is running or not (the file could also be open by an antivirus scanner or an entirely different program, and thus he *still* wouldn't be able to overwrite even if only one instance of the program was running).

Comment: @HeartWare: No matter. If there are other running instances, update is skipped.

Comment: @Hwau: But what if the file is open in another program? Or if it Read-Only? Or located on a network drive where you don't have write access? There are so many more possibilities that you still can't overwrite the file than simply if the program that called you doesn't run anymore...

Comment: @HEARTWARE So what. If something else has locked the file, then nothing else can succeed. Your polling is no exception.

Comment: @HeartWare: It can't happen

Comment: @Hwau: That's what one calls "Famous last words" :-)

Comment: @Hwau If you want to raise an error when CopyFile fails, do so. What makes you think that CopyFile does not report failure?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I was wrong, I can use GetLastError.Sorry

Comment: No. That's still wrong, or at best incomplete. You have to check the value returned by CopyFile first.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Sure. In the cases which file can be in use or blocked for some reason, do you think that CopyFile is the best way? (Avoiding polling, I mean)

Comment: CopyFile is a reasonable way to copy a file